# Why can't I use an anonymous function inside jasmine's expectAsync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jasmine

I am trying to do unit testing in Jasmine for my Nodejs Mongoose models. Everything works unless I transfer the code from a function block to an anonymous / arrow function. I cannot understand why it does not work using anonymous / arrow functions.

Here is my basic spec file:

```
const MongoDbTest = require('../lib/mongodb-tests.lib');
const Info = require("../models/info.model");

async function addTupleWithoutValue() {
  await new Info({ name: 'trududu' }).save();
}

describe("Le modèle Info", () => {
  const mongod = new MongoDbTest();

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await mongod.connect(); // This takes care of connecting to the database, etc.
  } );

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongod.close(); // This takes care of closing the connection, etc.
  } );

  // ... other tests removed

  it("a absolument besoin du champ 'value'", async () => {
    await expectAsync(async function() {
      await new Info({ name: 'trududu' }).save();
    } ).toBeRejectedWithError(/value: Path `value` is required/); // This does not work

    await expectAsync(addTupleWithoutValue()).toBeRejectedWithError(/value: Path `value` is required/); // this works
  } );
} );
```

And here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Mixed = mongoose.Mixed;

const InfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  value: { type: Mixed, required: true }
} );

module.exports = mongoose.model('Info', InfoSchema);
```

When I use the anonymous function (or an arrow function), Jasmine give me the following error message: `Error: Expected toBeRejectedWithError to be called on a promise.` Looking at the source code for Jasmine, the value returned by a function is checked by `function(obj) { return !!obj && j$.isFunction_(obj.then); }`. Does that mean that an anonymous function return a different kind of promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that I missed a tiny difference between the anonymous function and the function block. Did you spot it? Here it is:

```
await expectAsync(async function() {
  await new Info({ name: 'trududu' }).save();
} ).toBeRejectedWithError(/value: Path `value` is required/); // This does not work

await expectAsync(addTupleWithoutValue()).toBeRejectedWithError(/value: Path `value` is required/); // this works
```

The second one has an extra **()** which means that the function is called and returns a promise. The first one is simply the function definition, which means that `toBeRejectedWithError` fails because it expects a promise, not a function.

By adding **()** after the anonymous function definition, changing it into a function **call** (returning a promise), everything works like a charm.

I solved this before I posted my question but decided to finish posting it because I did not find any similar question. I hope this helps another fellow developer.

Comment: What you are missing is the difference between a function definition and a function call. It looks like `expectAsync` does not take a function as an argument but a value of type `Promise`.

Comment: Actually, since `expectAsync` expects a promise, wrapping it inside async/await is completely redundant: `await expectAsync(new Info({name:'trududu'}).save())` is the best way to write it

Comment: Yes, in this particular case, you're right. Most of my tests include several statements. Thanks for your precision concerning function calls, I will edit my answer.